# Functions separated by Commas in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm going through AngularJS authentication using this article: https://medium.com/opinionated-angularjs/techniques-for-authentication-in-angularjs-applications-7bbf0346acec#.y7nkgrxqo

In the article, they bring up:

```
.controller('LoginController', function ($scope, $rootScope, AUTH_EVENTS, AuthService) {
  $scope.credentials = {
    username: '',
    password: ''
  };
  $scope.login = function (credentials) {
    AuthService.login(credentials).then(function (user) {
      $rootScope.$broadcast(AUTH_EVENTS.loginSuccess);
      $scope.setCurrentUser(user);
    }, function () {
      $rootScope.$broadcast(AUTH_EVENTS.loginFailed);
    });
  };
})
```

The .then in $scope.login has two functions that are separated by a comma --- what does this mean?

Comment: Updated to reflect your comment

Answer (score 2):

`$scope.login` only has one function, `then()` has two functions, as in

```
promise.then(function(value) {
     // fulfillment
  }, function(reason) {
     // rejection
});
```

The first function is called when the promise is fulfilled. This function has one argument, the fulfillment value.

The second function is called when the promise is rejected. This function has one argument, the rejection reason.

[Promise.then()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then)

Answer (score 0):

If you read carefully, you can see that `$scope.login` has only one function. But the `Promise.then` callback for login has 2, one for success, one for failure. The first will be called if the login succeeded, second if the `login` failed.

```
AuthService
    .login(credentials)
    .then(
        // 1st callback (success)
        function (user) {
            // Login succeeded
            $rootScope.$broadcast(AUTH_EVENTS.loginSuccess);
            $scope.setCurrentUser(user);
        }, 
        // 2nd callback (failure)
        function () {
            // Login failed
            $rootScope.$broadcast(AUTH_EVENTS.loginFailed);
        }
    );
```

Comment: My fingers :-) Or webstorm.

Answer (score 0):

============Concept one, function as arguments =================

It's not an Angular feature, it's just plain javascript. Javascript will accept anything as an argument to a function, including other functions.
This is a quick way of breaking it down:

```
function ryu(){
    console.log('hadouken!');
}
function ken(){
    console.log('shoryuken!');
}
function fight(x,y){
    x();
    y();
}
```

This

```
fight(ryu,ken);
```

is the same as:

```
fight(function(){
    console.log('hadouken!');
},function(){
    console.log('shoryuken!');
});
```

============Concept two, promises =================

The promise thing everyone is talking about in the other answers is just a plus. Promises are a fancy way of 'do something after something'. A quick and dirty way of doing your promise is:

Let's say before the fight happens, a guy has to announce it.

```
function announce(fight,a,b){
    console.log('3,2,1 fight!');
    //fight will happen after 3 seconds
    setTimeout(function(){
        fight(a,b)
    },3000);
}

//then you run it
annount(fight,ryu,ken);
```